# Best practice for handling errors in forms submitted via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm wondering what is considered best practice for dealing with forms submitted via ajax. Specifically, I'm wondering what is the best way to handle a form which contains errors.

I see two possible options upon submitting a form with errors:

A. The server returns a JSON document of name value pairs of fields names / error messages. This would then need to be processed client-side and the form would need to be altered by prefixing each field with it's error message and changing the form's styling (adding an error class to the fields for example).

OR

B. The server simply returns a new HTML fragment containing the form with error messages and styles pre-applied. No need to process anything client-side except swap-out the form.

To me option B seems like the easier/quicker option but I can't help but feel that it isn't 'best practice'. Is there pros/cons for either method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separation of logic is a huge one here I reckon.

As a project grows, you generally have a front-end team and a back-end team. Imagine the website gets a huge makeover but the logic stays the same. Option B is harder to change the style when the layout is enforced server side.

The application logic (which is this case is server side validation) should be separate from the presentation layer (which is this case is the html/css rendered by the browser).

But at the end of the day, we get paid to produce results so if your not trying to win an academy award for best quality code, and you got bills to pay, just get it done the quickest way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the first option.
The second option just increases the load on the server ... which you always want to avoid. Plus, I feel that if the styling was done on the server-end, the your website isn't exactly modular ... all styling should be done on the front end only.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an opinion question but there are a few objective things to say about the topic. Your first option, the pure JSON choice is best used for apps that focus on speed an keeping HTTP requests as small as possible.

The other option, to process your form server-side then return the new form through AJAX doesn't seem to have too many advantages to me. If you're going that route then why bother with AJAX at all? Why not just do a regular form post to the server?

I usually prefer a front end validation and server-side verification. This way you can avoid a JSON call at all if things aren't valid but just in case someone sneaks something in there the server-side code will verify.

Comment: I'm wanting to use ajax because it's for a web app where I don't want to do a complete page refresh when the form is submitted. I've considered using an iframe containing the form but think I'd still like to go the ajax route.

Comment: @Groady Using JSON or HTML as an AJAX response is situational. Returning an entire form in HTML seems like overkill to me. Returning HTML fragments makes sense to me and that can simplify development. JSON is faster to transmit but if you have to parse through it to create HTML elements your users may not have fast computers to do that. Weigh your options and choose the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

I would establish a JSON scheme for validation on the front end. Just basic stuff like what you're checking for on each field, which fields are optional, etc... That gets baked into every page with a form on it. Then let your front end devs pre-validate to avoid unnecessary calls in whatever way makes the most sense to them.

Pre-built errors isn't against any best practice I'm aware of and it's not a terrible way to go (people tend to throw the UI manual of style out the window when it comes to forms anyway), but sometimes you'll want to give more specifics or different errors for different problems.

Always aim for having your cake and eating it too, IMO.